# Android Studio lost some lint item and reconfigure lint severity does NOT work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-lint

Lint checking reports some error like: NotSibling, ExtraTranslation, MissingTranslation...

In configure UI of link checking of Android Studio, I can NOT find "NotSibling" item, but Eclipse has it.

Also, re-configure severity of "MissingTranslation" and "ExtraTranslation" to "warning", it just does NOT work. Lint checking still report errors.

Answer (score 0):

create lint.xml in project's root dir and paste following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
      <issue id="MissingTranslation" severity="warning" />
      <issue id="DuplicateIds" severity="warning" />
      <issue id="Instantiatable" severity="warning" />
      <issue id="NotSibling" severity="warning" />
      <issue id="ExtraTranslation" severity="warning" />
      <issue id="ResourceType" severity="warning" />
</lint>
```

this will can make lint ignore the error.

However, I still don't know why AS's configure does not have NotSibling while Eclipse has.